# How does printer steganography work on monochrome laser printers?

Tags: printers

For purely cost reasons I've always used black and white laser printers. I'm particularly a fan of ML-2851ND for being cheap and easy to refill. It's my go to work horse. I'm wondering how people track these though.

I've seen yellow dots on color printers. The EFF says this,

> safest to assume that all modern **color** laser printers

What about the black and white ones? Has anyone determine any similar method on these? Is there a similar database that covers the monochrome laser printers?

From [Wikipedia on *"Printer Stenography"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_steganography)

> It has been reported that monochrome printers and copiers from major manufacturers also include the markings.[by whom?]

Comment: It must print individual dots in certain places at 1/600 or higher.  It would be nearly impossible to see a dot 1/600in by 1/600 in.

Comment: 600dpi would be doable. I have an ix500 scanner. The printer prints at 1200 dpi, so it could be dotting at 2x that resolution. But is it, is this a thing known to happen?

Comment: I don't know if it happens I just know they could do it.